# Как вызвать безрамочное окно Python, TKinter/PyGame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как можно вызвать безрамочное окно? Что бы не было белой рамки и кнопок 'закрыть', 'свернуть'.

Вот примеры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `root = tk.Tk()` `root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')`? По теме: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39530810/5909792 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31086299/5909792

Comment: сплэш конечно это то что показанно на картинке, но если внутри будет интерактив - нужно фрэймлес

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот код возможно там немного лишнего но если что уберете часть кода и все

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)#делает его поверх других окон
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)#ето запрещает растягивать окно tkinter
root.overrideredirect(1)#уберает края 
root.geometry("300x420+500+200")#задает размеры файла,и его кординаты

root.mainloop()
```